# Dagger 2 Scopes explanation

Tags: android, dependency-injection, scope, dagger, dagger-2

First of all , I am newbie, just starting to explore dagger, I have some problems with understanding, so hope someone can help me.

I have read a lot about dagger, but still cannot figure out some parts.

I created my `ApplicationComponent` and it looks like this

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ApplicationModule.class,
        ThreadingModule.class,
        NetworkModule.class,
        DatabaseModule.class,
        ServiceModule.class,
        ParseModule.class,
        PreferencesSessionModule.class})

public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);
    void inject(MainAppActivity mainAppActivity);
    void inject(BaseFragment baseFragment);
}
```

And it works great everything injects correctly, but now I wanna to dive deeper into dagger API and use `Custom Scope`

I have module called `PermissionModule` it is used for Android M versions.

```
@PerActivity
@Module
public class PermissionModule {
    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    PermissionController providePermissionController(Activity activity) {
        return new PermissionManager(activity);
    }
}
```

And I want to it to be injected into my activity and be in the memory only when activity is also in memory (actvity lifecycle)

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = {
        ActivityModule.class,
        PermissionModule.class
})
public interface ActivityComponent {
    Activity activity();

    void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);

    PermissionModule permissionModule();
}
```

My `ActivityComponent`

```
@PerActivity
@Component(modules = {
        ActivityModule.class,
        PermissionModule.class
})
public interface ActivityComponent {
    Activity activity();

    void inject(BaseActivity baseActivity);

    PermissionModule permissionModule();
}
```

And my `BaseActivity`

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SpiceManagerProvider, NetworkRequestsExecutor {
    // Dependencies are injected by ApplicationComponent
    @Inject
    protected ApplicationSettingsManager mApplicationSettingsManager;
    @Inject
    protected SpiceManager mSpiceManager;
    @Inject
    protected ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor mPoolExecutor;

    !!!!!!
    Should be injected by activity component 
    @Inject
    protected PermissionController mPermissionController;
```

And in `onCreate()`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Injecting dependencies
        MyApplication application = MyApplication.get(this);
        application.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
        DaggerActivityComponent.builder().activityModule(new ActivityModule(this)).build().inject(this);
        mPermissionController.requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
        mPermissionController.requestPermission(Manifest.permission.CAMERA);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

I got the error

> PermissionController cannot be provided without an @Provides- or
>   @Produces-annotated method.
>   .ui.activities.base.BaseActivity.mPermissionController

What is wrong in my code ?

Also not to create new question and it is related to this topic.

How does dagger2 parse `Scope` annotation, I cannot figure out this. As I understand dagger only recognizes `Singleton` annotation and all other annotations doesn't affect dagger decision, because all other annotations will have scope of activity ?

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is that you call the ApplicationComponent's inject method first

```
application.getApplicationComponent().inject(this);
```

which tries to inject all the members, including the PermissionController. But the ApplicationComponent can not provide this, and that is what Dagger complains about.

The solution is to only call the ActivityComponent's inject() method.

Most probably you do need dependencies provided by the ApplicationComponent at some point. To archive that, you'd need to combine the two components. Dagger provides two ways for that,[subcomponents](https://google.github.io/api/latest/dagger/Subcomponent.html) and [component dependencies](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/latest/dagger/Component.html#dependencies())

When using component dependencies, rou would end up with something like this in your Activity's onCreate() method:

```
 DaggerActivityComponent
            .builder()
            .applicationComponent(application.getApplicationComponent())
            .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
            .build().inject(this);
```

when you change your components to look something similar to this:

```
@PerActivity
@Component(
    dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, 
    modules = {
        ActivityModule.class,
        PermissionModule.class
    }
)
public interface ActivityComponent {
    ...
}
```

note that you need to provide dependencies explicitly in the ApplicationComponent when you need it in the ActivityComponent (or any injectors)

Comment: Thank you for answer, only thing I wonder is it clean way to do so ? Or maybe there is another option ?

Comment: as I mentioned you can do this with subcomponents as well. but other than combining the dependency graph and using the result to resolve dependencies, I don't think that there is a cleaner solution. scoping also only makes sense if you have only one object graph. otherwise you might end up with multiple instances for a scope.

Answer (score 0):

If there is any dependency from parent component ( for instance @Componenet (model=AppModel.class) public interface appComponent... ) that you want to use in child component (@ActivityScope @Component (DEPENDENCY=APPCOMPONENT.class, model= ActivityModel.class) public interface activityComponenet... ) you need to expose it in parent component. Only exposed dependencies are accessible downstream (in child components). You do it by writing method from appModel that need to provide dependency downstream in appComponenet interface. Name of the method do not need to match the name of method in appModel, only the return type count.

Answer (score -1):

About your confusion on Dagger scopes , I am hereby specifying some conclusions regarding scopes

- Any time a un-scoped service is being injected by the same component, a new instance of a service is created.
- First time a @Singleton scoped service is being injected, it is instantiated and cached inside the injecting component, and then the same exact instance will be used upon injection into other fields of the same type by the same component.
- Custom user-defined scopes are functionally equivalent to a predefined @Singleton Scope
- Injection of scoped services is thread safe.

If you really want to clearly understand how internally Dagger uses singleton and custom scope , follow this article [Dagger 2 Scopes : How It Works Internally](https://medium.com/@er.abhishek.luthra/dagger-2-scopes-unriddled-f5c3f2f2dff2)

Comment: very good answer, only problem this is a blut **plagiat**!!! Dude - copy-pasting others work, and reposting on Medium as your own... that's just low.
Here's the source, dating 2 years before your's:
https://www.techyourchance.com/dagger-2-scopes-demystified/
Judge for your self.